# How to create Virtual Hosts within a NAS directory

Tags: permissions, samba, nfs

When I try to set up a virtual host I need to change my permissions for the root directory like this:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /NAS/directory
sudo chmod 755 /NAS/directory
```

But whenever I do it I keep getting errors like:

> chown: changing ownership of '/NAS/directory': Invalid argument
>
> chmod: changing permissions of '/NAS/directory': Invalid argument

Why is this happening??

I have my directory for my nas set up like this using multiple hard drives:

```
#External HDD's
UUID="54E1-D75E" /mount1 exfat utf8,auto,rw,nobootwait,umask=0,sec=ntlm 0 0
UUID="54F9-A540" /mount2 exfat utf8,auto,rw,nobootwait,umask=0,sec=ntlm 0 0
UUID="1B81-6E61" /mount3 exfat utf8,auto,rw,nobootwait,umask=0,sec=ntlm 0 0
UUID="54ED-E111" /mount4 exfat utf8,auto,rw,nobootwait,umask=0,sec=ntlm 0 0

#mount to NAS

mhddfs#/mount1,/mount2,/mount3,/mount4 /NAS fuse defaults,allow_other,nobootwait,nonempty 0 0
```